# PHP & DOM - get number of nodes, delete oldest and add new one as first

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have flash photo gallery with simple PHP uploader.

In uploader.php file I have added code which store last 20 added photos into xml file.

The script for saving data in xml file I have already done, and xml structure looks like this:

```
<images>
     <image thumb="/content/photos/tn_PICTURE1.jpg" image="/content/photos/PICTURE1.jpg" name="PICTURE1"/>
     <image thumb="/content/photos/tn_PICTURE2.jpg" image="/content/photos/PICTURE2.jpg" name="PICTURE2"/>
     <image thumb="/content/photos/tn_PICTURE3.jpg" image="/content/photos/PICTURE3.jpg" name="PICTURE3"/>
     ...
     <image thumb="/content/photos/tn_PICTURE20.jpg" image="/content/photos/PICTURE20.jpg" name="PICTURE20"/>
</images>
```

The part of uploader.PHP file:

```
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$domtree->load("new_files.xml");
$root = $domtree->documentElement;
$currentImage = $domtree->createElement("image");
$currentImage = $root->appendChild($currentImage);

$thumb = $domtree->createAttribute("thumb");
$currentImage->appendChild($thumb);
$thumbValue = $domtree->createTextNode($thumbnail);
$thumb->appendChild($thumbValue);

$imagelink = $domtree->createAttribute("image");
$currentImage->appendChild($imagelink);
$imageValue = $domtree->createTextNode($fullpath);
$imagelink->appendChild($imageValue);

$imagename = $domtree->createAttribute("name");
$currentImage->appendChild($imagename);
$imagenameValue = $domtree->createTextNode($imageName);
$imagename->appendChild($imagenameValue);

$domtree->save("new_files.xml");
```

What I want to do?

When is more than 20 pictures in xml file, then I want that script will automaticaly deleting last one (oldest), and put the newest one as first. So the result will looks like this:

```
<images>
     <image thumb="/content/photos/tn_PICTURE21.jpg" image="/content/photos/PICTURE21.jpg" name="PICTURE21"/>
     <image thumb="/content/photos/tn_PICTURE1.jpg" image="/content/photos/PICTURE1.jpg" name="PICTURE1"/>
     <image thumb="/content/photos/tn_PICTURE2.jpg" image="/content/photos/PICTURE2.jpg" name="PICTURE2"/>
     ...
     <image thumb="/content/photos/tn_PICTURE19.jpg" image="/content/photos/PICTURE19.jpg" name="PICTURE19"/>
</images>
```

Any suggestions?

Ps. Sorry for my bad english :)

Regards, Artur.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the SimpleXML object?  It is far easier to use if you are just dealing with XML.

After that, all you need to do is load up the XML file and do something like this:

```
$uploadedFilesCount = count($uploadedFiledArray);

$currentIndex = 0;
while($totalIndex < $uploadedFilesCount){
    foreach($YourSweetXMLObject->children() as $child){
        $child->attributes()->thumbs = $uploadedFiledArray[$currentIndex]['thumbs'];
        $child->attributes()->image = $uploadedFiledArray[$currentIndex]['image'];
        $child->attributes()->name = $uploadedFiledArray[$currentIndex]['name'];

        $totalIndex++;   
    }
}
```

The only problem is, if you upload again, it will start from the top of your XML object.  If you want to be able to start from a different point in your XML file,  you are going to need to store more information.

Hope that helps.